# Grabbing first image for each object in Parse iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, parse-platform

Sorry for the poorly worded title.  I have a logic issue that I'm trying to get my head around.  The view that I'm working in has a `UICollectionView` that displays a list of "tanks" associated with a user.  This collection view displays a three items:

- Tank Name
- Tank Capacity
- Last Image Stored

The last image stored part is where I'm having trouble.  I'm making progress but its a matter of the logic behind it that I'm not sure on.  Here is what the data looks like:

I have two classes that I'm interacting with; `SavedTanks` and `SavedTankImages`.  The unique `objectId` from a saved tank is also stored as a value in `SavedTankImages` to allow a sort of pointer reference to the image.  This logic works when the user loads a "tank" and can see all of the images they've stored associated with it.

However, for the purposes of this view, I only need to grab the first image from each tank and display that.  This is where I need help.  Here's what I have so far:

```
#pragma mark COLLECTION VIEW
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
photoHandler *cell = (photoHandler *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
_tankNameArray = [_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section * 1 + indexPath.row];
cell.tankNameLabel.text = [_tankNameArray valueForKey:@"tankName"];
cell.tankCapLabel.text = [_tankNameArray valueForKey:@"tankCapacity"];
NSArray *objectId = [_array valueForKey:@"objectId"];

for (int i = 0; i < objectId.count; i++)
{
    NSString *objectString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    objectString = [objectId objectAtIndex:i];

    PFQuery *imageQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SavedTankImages"];
    [imageQuery whereKey:@"tankObjectId" equalTo:objectString];
    [imageQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {
            for (PFObject *object in objects)
            {
                NSLog(@"OBJECT TEST: %@", object);
            }
        }
    }];
}
return cell;
}
```

On `OBJECT TEST: %@`, this is the logged output:

```
2014-05-28 11:59:44.750 ReefTrack[305:60b] OBJECT TEST: <SavedTankImages:U6fRTuRo2c:    (null)> {
tankImages = "<PFFile: 0x18a25890>";
tankObjectId = tsz4yvrIAN;
}
```

`SavedTankImages: <x>` is the `objectId` of the individual image, and `tankObjectId` is the tank the image is associated with.  I'm getting close, but I need to know how I can effectively iterate and only grab the first item where `tankObjectId` matches the original `objectId`.  Please forgive me if this sounds a little convoluted.

Thanks for the help in advance as usual.

**UPDATE**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    photoHandler *cell = (photoHandler *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    _tankNameArray = [_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section * 1 + indexPath.row];
    cell.tankNameLabel.text = [_tankNameArray valueForKey:@"tankName"];
    cell.tankCapLabel.text = [_tankNameArray valueForKey:@"tankCapacity"];
    NSArray *objectId = [_array valueForKey:@"objectId"];

    for (int i = 0; i < objectId.count; i++)
    {
//        NSString *objectString = [[NSString alloc] init];
//        objectString = [objectId objectAtIndex:i];
        PFQuery *imageQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SavedTankImages"];
        [imageQuery whereKey:@"tankObjectId" equalTo:[objectId objectAtIndex:i]];
        [imageQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *objects, NSError *error)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                PFFile *imageFile = [objects valueForKey:@"tankImages"];
                [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error)
                    {
                        cell.parseImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    }
                }];
                NSLog(@"Heres your image: %@", objects);
            }
        }];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The above code selects the first available image and makes it the background for every cell in `collectionView`.  I want to get it so that it only returns the first image for the objectId.  In other words

- Tank 1 = tank 1 image 1
- Tank 2 = tank 2 image 1
- Tank 3 = tank 3 image 1

Right now this is what it's doing:

- Tank 1 = tank 1 image 1
- Tank 2 = tank 1 image 1
- Tank 3 = tank 1 image 1

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? So your current code is pulling ALL images related to that tank and you just want the most RECENT one, correct?

Comment: That's correct.  I only want to pull the latest associated with each tank and display that.  The use case here is a list of tanks associated with the user, and instead of a tableView i'm using a collectionView so I can display the images easily.  Most of it is working.  The only thing that's not is grabbing the first image to display that

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, sort and take just the first result. Be aware this isn't as efficient as the next solution:

```
// sort by createdAt or use updatedAt
[imageQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
// change from find to getFirst
//[imageQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
[imageQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {
        NSLog(@"OBJECT TEST: %@", object);
    }
}];
```

A more advanced solution if you'll often be querying on this is to store a pointer to the most recent object on the tank. You can either do this in your code or create a Cloud Code method to update it automatically after each `SavedTankImages` object is saved (it would simply load up the related `SavedTanks` and set `mostRecentImage` to point to the saved image, then save the `SavedTanks`).

If you have done this, then you can just use the `include:` method to load the `mostRecentImage` with the `SavedTanks`.

Comment: Updated the code; it's only half doing what I want it to do, I'm closer now though.